# I would like to see if Ubuntu would like to implement A.I. into the operating system

Tags: 22.04, accessibility

Will Ubuntu ever implement AI into the operating system? I'm asking this question, because some people have some form of disability, or need help navigating thru Ubuntu.. I would want to see AI sometime into Ubuntu. I have created a chatbot that helps people navigate thru Ubuntu, but it is still under development. I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask, but I'd like Ubuntu to implement AI so that people with disabilities can navigate, like for example if someone didn't know how to get online, didn't know where the launcher is, or didn't know how to install software and it would tell you instructions. I can also train the chatbot, as it just basically uses a terminal program. If this is wrong place to post this, please reply and please tell me where to post this question at.

Comment: You seem to be using "disability" to distract from UTBLT! (Using Tool Before Learning Tool)

Comment: Never heard of UTBLT, but how you phrased "to distract from UTBLT", it appears like that I am going against someone, and/or I am doing something wrong. I have used Ubuntu since 2006.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is mostly a "distro." Ubuntu specializes in integrating and *distributing* software from many upstream projects.

Making an environment more accessible is most usefully discussed and developed at that project. Those improvements will automatically flow into Ubuntu.

- Example: The Gnome Desktop Environment is developed by the [Gnome Project](https://wiki.gnome.org/) (not by Ubuntu). The [Gnome Accessibility Team](https://wiki.gnome.org/Accessibility) pays attention to accessibility issues in Gnome.

Comment: I understand it is a distribution. I'd like to see AI implemented so that people can navigate thru the operating system for people who need help navigating, and/or for people who have some form of disability.

Comment: @wyattmoon sure, hence the second paragraph and example. It seems this answer addresses only one segment of your broader vision. Perhps other answers will address other elements.

Comment: You're wrong. My vision, is more expanding. My vision, is to expand this chatbot so it can download programs, install software, and change settings that the user wants changed. Technology is evolving, so until that kind has been made available from technology I am still training my chatbot. I have been training this chatbot for 30 years.